# Trigger ZenScroll from external link

Tags: javascript, scroll

Is it possible to use ZenScroll (https://github.com/zengabor/zenscroll) to link in and scroll to a specific section from an external site? E.g. clicking example.com/#somesection on the first page and have it trigger with, say, the window history object?
Any ideas/directions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a clean way to do it but you can work around it if you can control how the external site links to you site, and you don't mind if no scroll will happen in case JavaScript doesn't work in the user's browser.

Example:

1. External site links to `https://yoursite.com/#somesection`
2. However, the page `https://yoursite.com/` doesn't have the any element with id `somesection`, so the browser won't automatically scroll anywhere.
3. Your custom JavaScript on this page detects that `window.location.hash` was set to `#somesection` which translates to `#mysection` so you invoke an animated scroll to that element:
   `if (window.location.hash==="#somesection") zenscroll.to(document.getElementById("mysection"))`